# Как повернуть матрицу на 180 градусов и 270 против часовой стрелки?

Tags: java, матрицы

Написал метод поворота двумерной матрицы на 90 градусов против часовой стрелки.

```
private static int SIZE = 8;
private static int[][] colors = new int[SIZE][SIZE];

public static void reverseMatrix90() {
    int[][] rotatedMatrix = new int[colors.length][colors.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < colors.length; j++) {
            rotatedMatrix[i][j] = colors[colors.length - j - 1][i];
        }
    }
    colors = rotatedMatrix;
}
```

Как написать аналогичный метод `reverseMatrix180()`  и `reverseMatrix270()` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто рассмотрите, как координаты трансформируются:

180:

```
rotatedMatrix[i][j] = colors[colors.length - i - 1][colors.length - j - 1];
```

270 (-90):

```
rotatedMatrix[i][j] = colors[j][colors.length - i - 1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Если функция поворота на 90 корректна - то:

1. переделать эту функцию, чтобы принимала на себя матрицу и возвращала её

   ```
   public static int[][] reverseMatrix90(int[][] matrix)
   ```
2. 180 вызвать функцию reverseMatrix90 дважды

   ```
   return reverseMatrix90(reverseMatrix90(colors));
   ```
3. 270 вызвать функцию `reverseMatrix90` трижды

   ```
   return reverseMatrix90(reverseMatrix90(reverseMatrix90(colors)));
   ```

   или вызвать функцию `reverseMatrix180` и `reverseMatrix90`

   ```
   return reverseMatrix180(reverseMatrix90(colors));
   ```